# Возвращение ID пользователя

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите, как в i-Frame приложении для Вконтакте, при помощи Вконтакте API реализовать следующую задачу:
Человек заходит в I-Frame приложение
На экран выводится ID Вконтакте этого человека

//Для этого нужно будет использовать users.get
Прошу дать мне полный исходник HTML файлов, чистого JS со всеми подключениями, функциями и выводом на экран, я тогда разберусь, что и как в Вконтакте API

Comment: Вам нужен именно полный исходник? А с комментариями на каком языке?

Comment: @Семен Савенко, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iFrame приложения сразу при запуске через ВК уже получают набор GET параметров. Вас интересует как минимум параметр `viewer_id` который содержит как раз id пользователя.
Его разумеется, легко подделать, и поэтому стоит проверять второй параметр - подпись запроса - `auth_key`. Как это делать, [читайте](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5).

Comment: Ответь на мой вопрос: мне нужен исходник

Comment: С каких пор мы на "Ты"?